# Deploying React and ASP.NET Core (Preview)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, web, vite

I'm developing my first React and Dotnet app, but I'm stuck on deploying it. I started with the React and ASP.NET Core (Preview) template, which creates a separate .NET 7 API and Vite SPA. The app is working in Visual Studio's debug mode, and I have built the webapi and reactapp separately, but I'm not sure how to join the two.

How do I go about publishing and deploying these two separate pieces?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022  theres a section for publishing

Comment: @Josh somehow I missed this. Thanks for sharing!